# How to customize the bash prompt in a way that doesn't squash venv

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, prompt

I was a long time tcsh user and I have used a custom prompt, which includes the date/time, host, and a largish path.  In the past, when I've used venv, I would switch to bash first, just because everything's geared toward bash, and I liked that the current environment would be added to the prompt, and I had left the bash prompt uncustomized.  However, since I've been using bash more and more, I decided to migrate a version of my custom tcsh prompt.  To do that, I added this to my bash profile:

```
changeprompt() { DIR=`dirs | perl -e '$p=scalar(<STDIN>);$p=~s/.*(?=\S{40}\Z)/.../;print($p)'`;export PS1="\h[\D{%F %T}]:$DIR\$ "; }
PROMPT_COMMAND="changeprompt"
```

It leaves me with a prompt like this:

```
gen-rl-macbookair[2021-02-12 14:01:24]:~/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE$
```

I wanted a longer path in the prompt that is manually truncated with an ellipsis at a given length based on characters instead of directory depth, which is why I set `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

However, I realized yesterday when I started working on a venv for the first time in a long time, that activating a venv would not change the prompt to prepend `(environment_name)` to the prompt, since I had set `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

I fixed the issue by editing the activate script to unset `COMMAND_PROMPT` upon activate and reset `COMMAND_PROMPT` upon deactivate...

But I'm wondering if there exists a better way to maintain a custom command prompt like this that allows for a variably prepended string that a venv activate script adds - without needing custom edits to any activate script.

Comment: Problem is the activate venv setup script use `PS1` instead of `COMMAND_PROMPT`

Comment: Yeah. That's the problem. `PS1` features don't support the feature I want of limiting the path length, which is why I use `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  I want to see as many dirs of my path within 40 characters. That's what my `PROMPT_COMMAND` does. I think all I should need to do is store the old prompt command when a new env gets activated and restore it when deactivated. Or maybe I can change my prompt command to use the existing PS1 value, or modify it instead of set it.

Answer (score 0):

As a (bad) workaround, you can define bash functions that set and unset prefix for `PS1`, and call these when you activate/deactivate your venv instead of `source activate` and `deactivate`.

In your bashrc:

```
export PROMPT_PREFIX=
set_prompt_prefix(){
    PS1=$PROMPT_PREFIX$PS1
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='changeprompt && set_prompt_prefix'

activate_venv(){
    source activate && PROMPT_PREFIX="(venv) " && alias 'deactivate'='deactivate_venv'
}

deactivate_venv(){
    deactivate && PROMPT_PREFIX=
}
```

Then you have to call `activate_venv` instead of `source activate`. `deactivate` venv base function is aliased with my `deactivate_venv` so that prefix is always removed.

Beware that the prefix will always be `(venv)` . An even smarter solution could retrieve the venv name or directory and set it as prefix.

Comment: The venvs I have, have their own activate scripts that modify `PS1` and add different prefixes.  My error-prone workaround has been to edit those scripts to set/restore `PROMPT_COMMAND`, but other venvs tend to get in the way and I end up with stale prompts that don't update. Part of the problem (with my question) is I over-simplified the example. I should probably add more detail and examples to my question. Like, the activate scripts take a path, and switching between different venvs, etc.. This is a decent idea though.

Comment: Editing each new venv you create seems really painful for me since it all supposed to be auto-generated. Problem root is that python does not consider any use case like ours when we are working with `PROMPT_COMMAND` is might be a good idea to ask for a change request or warn for a bug somewhere.

Comment: It is. Hence my question. That's a good suggestion.